# I can view array data but cannot access it after fetch

Tags: arrays, dictionary, fetch, undefined

I have a function that creates a component based on the number of items (goals) in an array. I keep getting an error that the function cannot map 'goals' of undefined. Based on the research I've done, it is trying to map before the data is there. When testing this, I can console log the projects but cant access the array. I originally was using axios but I replicated the same problem using fetch. I have also tried conditionally rendering the components to no avail. I am also using 'useEffect'. I'd appreciate any help on this.

My state(I've tried both an empty object and array to initialize):

```
const [projs, setProjs] = useState({});
```

My fetch:

```
    async function getProjects(){
    await fetch(`${config.api.invokeUrl}/users/${11111}`)
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(data => {
           setProjs(data);
       });
```

};

And my map function:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    // fetchProjects();
    getProjects();

  }, []);

  let index = 0;

  
const createGoal =  projs[current].goals && projs[0].goals.map(goal => {
    return <Goal 
        goalDetails={goal} 
        projectManager={projectManager}
        index={index++}
        />
})
```

.
console.log("projects",projs.projects)

returns an array of projects

```
console.log("projects",projs.projects[0])
```

returns "cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the async/await with .then's were redundant so I changed my fetch to this:

```
    async function getProjects(){
    let response = await fetch(`${config.api.invokeUrl}/users/${11111}`);
    let data = await response.json();
    setProjects(data.projects)
     };
```

Created a goals variable and created a ternary against it:

```
    const goals = projects[current].goals
let createGoal = goals ? goals.map(goal => {
    return <Goal 
        goalDetails={goal} 
        projectManager={projectManager}
        index={index++}
        />
})
: 'loading'
```

And lastly I had to change my initial state to be an object within an array. It wont work if just an empty array, object or null

```
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([{}]);
```